# Key alias access issue - Android App Export

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Having a nightmare today!  I'm trying to add an update to our company's App, I'm using the same keystore I have used previously and what i'm sure is the password - but I just get the error 'keystore was tampered with, or password incorrect'.

Can I reset it anyway?  I've tried making a different keystore - but android marketplace wont accept it!!

Nightmare - any advice to solve this issue - and save me getting into some serious bother would be great-fully received!

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Change the keystore password using the following command

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore my.keystore
```